# Can a malware file in a .zip file be executed when testing the .zip file?

Tags: file-management, zip, malware, file-archiver

OS : Windows 10

Can a malware file in a .zip file be executed when testing the .zip file?

I mean, for example, testing by 7-zip context menu 'test archive'.

The .zip file has no password and just stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume it's safe.

Theoretically an exploit could exist in a particular program that could be used to run some code just by making the program look at it. These kinds of bugs are rather rare though and would probably be found and fixed long ago in any program that's been around for a while.

The same applies to other file formats, not just ZIP, with the exception of formats that support scripting like `.doc`.

Comment: Also thank you for explaining the term 'exploit '.